# prevent contact form 7 from submission on certain condition

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a contact form 7 form and in that I have an acceptance checkbox for terms and condition and I want to make that checkbox required and add some class when checkbox is not checked and prevent form from submission.So I tried using preventDefault().

```
<script>
$(".wpcf7-form).submit(function(event){
if($("#checkbox1").hasClass("check") == false){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#checkbox1).addClass("error");
} else {
  $("#checkbox1).removeClass("error");
});
</script>
```

Now addclass line is working and for some reason preventDefault() is not working it is submitting my form everytime regardless of checkbox state.I want to make that checkobx required but I dont want to use acceptance's optional field as I dont want to disable my submit button.
Any help will be helpful and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into using the Acceptance checkbox CF7 offers that is meant specifically for what you are trying here? https://contactform7.com/acceptance-checkbox/

Comment: @kraftner, I already tried all the parameters if i use  [acceptance id: acceptancecheckbox1 class:form-control-input acceptance_as_validation: on ][/acceptance] then submit button is getting disabled but if i use optional with acceptance _as_validation then form is getting submitted regardless of checkbox state .

Comment: @kraftner, my bad acceptance_as_validation is a additional settings. Yeah it worked I check acceptance_as_validation multiple times trying to figure out the solution but didn't see it was additional settings. Well thanks

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still trying figure out the solution there is a additional settings which works like normal contact form 7 validation for other field just use `acceptance_as_validation: on`.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your submit button when your condition is met. That should do the job.

```
$('.wpcf7-form').submit(function(event) {
    var submitButton = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
    if ( $('#checkbox1').hasClass('check') == false ) {
        $('#checkbox1').addClass('error');
        submitButton.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        $('#checkbox1').removeClass('error');
        submitButton.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to disable submit button just if acceptance is not check  don't submit the form just show error that accept terms and conditions or something.